# Serializing JSON string to Match WCF Service Function Parameter

Tags: c#, wcf, json, rest

I am facing problem serializing an object in JSON to match parameter name of WCF function call. The problem is to map the parameter name, i.e. the incoming JSON string should have the starting value as the  same name as the parameter being passed in the function e.g.

```
"{\"GetComplexDataResult\":{\"BoolValue\":true,\"StringValue\":\"Hello World!\"}}"
```

This is my WCF Function which I call in my client and as you can see the parameter name is same as the one which is being returned "GetComplexDataResult"

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
String SaveData(CompositeType GetComplexDataResult);
```

The problem which occurs is when I try to serialize my object using either Microsoft `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` or any other library (e.g. Json.NET)

it only returns me `{\"BoolValue\":true,\"StringValue\":\"Hello World!\"}` even if I pass an object of the same class "CompositeType" (This is the client side code) e.g.

```
CompositeType GetComplexDataResult= new CompositeType();
GetComplexDataResult.BoolValue = true;
GetComplexDataResult.StringValue = "Hello World";

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize(patchVersion);
```

My question is how can I get this JSON string

```
"{\"GetComplexDataResult\":{\"BoolValue\":true,\"StringValue\":\"Hello World!\"}}"
```

Instead of

```
{\"BoolValue\":true,\"StringValue\":\"Hello World!\"}
```

with by just passing my object to JSON parser. I can concatenate it manually after I generate my JSON string, but that would be too much time consuming work. Is there any parser which solves this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you serialize an anonymous object using the parameter name as a property name, it will include it in the json string.  Try this:

```
string json = serializer.Serialize(new { GetComplexDataResult = patchVersion});
```

Also, if you don't care whether the parameter name is included in the JSON at all, you can set the `BodyStyle` to `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare`.

Answer (score 2):

My question is, is there a significant reason you need to have `\"GetComplexDataResult\"` at the beginning of the json data?

I do not believe the json serializers will do what you want them to natively, you pretty much have to handle it yourself.

What we do at the company I work for, is we build our own response wrapper that makes all our responses the same format for all our json services.  So pretty much we make a standard datacontract that returns a datacontract for one of the properties of the outter wrapper.  You could do something like that to get the "nesting" functionality you are looking for.

Here is an example:

```
[DataContract]
    public class ServiceResult<T>
    {
        [DataMember]
        public T GetComplexDataResult{ get; set; }
    }
```

**UPDATE**: Modified this to be generic.  wanted to further explain where I was going with my original answer.  Again adrift's answer is more concise, just keep in mind if you wanted to expand, like add messaging, you would have to do something like this, or manually do it yourself.  I really like this approach because I know what my format will always be the same no matter which of our WCF services I call.

Comment: Yes, as  WCF maps names in the JSON string to parameters passed to functions e.g. String SaveData(CompositeType GetComplexDataResult) has a parameter named "GetComplexDataResult" and to map value to this object the JSON string should be "{\"GetComplexDataResult\":{\"BoolValue\":true,\"StringValue\":\"Hello World!\"}}". I need to see how much creating a wrapper around my objects would help me.

Comment: I do the exact same thing as you want, as I noted, but we wrap it in a generic outter ServiceResult<T> contract where the inner property is  public T[] Data { get; set; }.  So the returned data is always in the "Data" json returned.  The answer by adrift essentially does the exact same thing, you get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

For every JSON parser I've seen - the object type is never included in the JSON. The serialization represents an instance of that object. You would be better off adding a `type` attribute if you need to know the object source type reference. `{\"BoolValue\":true,\"StringValue\":\"Hello World!\",\"type\":\"GetComplexDataResult\"}`.

Your output scarily reminds me of a SOAP envelope. You don't need the encapsulation - it just makes it more complex. JSON is simple - keep it simple.

Comment: The problem here is not about the type its about adding the object name "GetComplexDataResult" at the beginning of the generated JSON. WCF maps names from the JSON string and the parameters you have passed to function. WCF json response is like this, "{\"GetComplexDataResult\":{\"BoolValue\":true,\"StringValue\":\"Hello World!\"}}" and as i am calling a function using GET it automatically appends  the function name "GetComplexData" and extra "Result" attribute to it. So, I was thinking that there could be a way around of doing this as WCF is doing so it must be possible.